# How to reset Redux toolkit query state (query, not mutation)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

In Redux toolkit query we write as follows in mutations:

```js
const [purchase, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess, reset }] = useCreateOneSaleMutation()
```

and we can use the **reset** method to reset the state.

Is there a way I can do the same in the query hooks?

```js
const { isLoading, isError, isSuccess, reset } = useGetOneSale()
```

- we can do `refetch` which actually exists, but I need something to **reset** these states in a component on call, so I need a **reset** method.

Is it supported in redux toolkit query?

I depend on `isSuccess` in a useEffect to render some logic, and I need this `isSuccess` to reset back to false when the component unmounts.

I have a modal, and when this modal closes, it should reset back to false, because the useEffect looks as follows:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
   switch(true){
      case isSuccess:
        setText('Transaction completed successfully!')
      break
      default:
        setText('Please Enter The client id')
   }
}, [isSuccess])
```

so there must be something like

```js
useEffect(()=> ()=> reset())
```

in order for this kind of logic to work.

Comment: You might be able to use the `providesTags` and `invalidatesTags` mechanisms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RTK Query handles this sort of query-resetting through "tags".  Check out the [docs section on Automated Re-fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching).

Where you define your API endpoints, you will say that the `getOneSale` query **provides** a tag called `"OneSale"` (or whatever you want to call it).  Then say that your `createOneSale` mutation **invalidates** that tag.

```
const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: /* ... */,
  tagTypes: ['OneSale'],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getOneSale: build.query({
      query: /* ... */,
      providesTags: ['OneSale'],
    }),
    createOneSale : build.mutation({
      query: /* ... */,
      invalidatesTags: ['OneSale'],
    }),
  }),
})
```

When your `useCreateOneSaleMutation` execute call succeeds it will invalidate the `'OneSale'` tag and RTK will automatically re-fetch any `useGetOneSaleQuery` hooks.

---

If you need to invalidate a tag by some other means (not by a mutation) you can do this by [dispatching an `invalidateTags` action](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#invalidatetags).

```
dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags(['OneSale']));
```

Comment: The `dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags(['OneSale']));` was the part I was looking for, thank you Linda