# Redux toolkit query reset query state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a table with users where each user can be in loading state, e.g display loading spinner in user's row. When loading state on BE ended, FE still display loading indicator. I decided to make logic, that each 5 seconds make API call to check if user is still in loading state.

I have query which returns users which are displayed in table.

```
const {
    data: users,
    refetch: usersRefetch
} = useGetUsersQuery()
```

Them I have similar query, which call exactly same API endpoint, but is used for comparing with original data which are currently displayed in the table.

```
const [trigger, {
    data: usersValidator,
    isSuccess: usersValidatorIsSuccess
}] = useLazyGetUsersValidatorQuery()
```

And them I have an useEffect which compare original data with validator data

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (usersValidatorIsSuccess) {
            if (JSON.stringify(users) != JSON.stringify(usersValidator)) {
                refetch()
            } else {
                trigger()
            }
        }
    }, 2000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
}, [usersValidatorIsSuccess])
```

There's problem that usersValidatorIsSuccess has the same value - true, so useEffect run only once.
Is there some elegant way how to reset RTK query isSuccess state on demand?
I found this solution

[How to reset Redux toolkit query state (query, not mutation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829321/how-to-reset-redux-toolkit-query-state-query-not-mutation)

But it's look not nice, is there better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I thought that mutations are only for POST/PUT/DELETE and then invalidate tags.

But my case is little bit edge. I decided to use mutation for GET method.

```
getUsersValidator: build.mutation({
    query: (payload) => {
        return {
            url: "/users",
            method: "GET"
        }
    }
})
```

Then I can use reset method.